# Java Generics: Behavior of parameterized methods in a parameterized class

Tags: java, generics

How is this behavior of parameterized methods in a parameterized class explained in runtime?
I couldn't find a better explanation for this behavior in the documentation.
Why is the second method launched at runtime in the second case?

```
class SomeGenClass<T> {

    T var;

    public T getVar() {
        return var;
    }

    public void setVar(T var) {
        this.var = var;
    }

    public SomeGenClass(T var) {
        this.var = var;
    }

    public <E> void print(Collection<E> collection) {
        System.out.print(var.toString());
        for (E e : collection) {
            System.out.print(e);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void print(List<Integer> list) {
        System.out.println(var.toString());
        for (Integer i : list) {
            System.out.print(i);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("a"));

        SomeGenClass<?> gen = new SomeGenClass("1");
        gen.print(list); // Output: 1 a

        SomeGenClass gRaw = new SomeGenClass("2");
        gRaw.print(list); // Output: 2   + ClassCastException

    }
}
```

Comment: When you use raw types, all checks go out the window. The compiler will give you plenty of warnings about it. It's 2023, there's no reason to use raw types any more.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you cease using `var` as a variable name, since [it is a keyword in the Java language](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-14.html#jls-LocalVariableDeclaration) now.

Answer (score 1):

In java, 'raw mode' is infectious. Any expression is either 'raw' or it is not, and if its raw, **all parts of it are**, even in this case, where you have 2 essentially unrelated aspects (the `<E>` of your `<E> print(Collection<E>)` method, and the `<T>` on the class).

Here, `gRaw.print(list)` is a raw expression because `gRaw` is raw and raw infects the entire expression you use it in. That makes `print` raw, and thus javac acts as if print reads: `void(Collection c)`, with the generics binding to its lowest bound (Object). Which makes that list call compilable (even if it is obviously going to result in ClassCastExceptions at runtime).

The solution? Simple. When the compiler tells you via a warning that raw mode is being applied, **stop**. If you must dip into raw mode, insulate it from the rest of the code base as much as you can in helper methods, and `@SuppressWarnings` now.